# self clean while door open

Tags: equipment

Somehow the oven was set to self clean while the door was open, now the lock is engaged and wont close properly. It never did heat up, but the lock engaged. Any thoughts?

It is a frigidaire, by electrolux, don't know which model.

Comment: How long is the self-clean cycle? You could wait for that amount of time to pass and see if it unlocks. Alternatively, you could unplug it, wait a few minutes.  and plug it in again to see if rebooting it helps. If neither works, you may have to contact a repair person.

Comment: @JamesMcLeod That's a good answer. It's worthy of being an answer.

Comment: This question would be better asked at the manufacturer's help line 1 (800) 374-4432

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it not is about food or cooking, but about a technical problem.

Comment: Questions about kitchen equipment are on-topic, but that being said, there aren't really enough details in the question...

Answer (score 1):

As SAJ14SAJ points out, the manufacturer is likely to give you the best answer, so you should contacting Electrolux - either through their [Product Support page](http://www.electroluxappliances.com/Owner-Support/Product-Support/), or through their toll-free number (1-877-435-3287 in the US).

That said, I think this is expected behavior - the self-cleaning system will lock the door for the duration of the cycle, but the safety interlock will keep the oven from heating up if the door is not closed. There are two obvious things you could try (since this might happen when the Electrolux customer service department is not open):

1. Just wait for the normal cycle time to end, and the door lock should open allowing you to close it properly.
2. Unplug the stove for a while (three or four seconds should be enough, but just to be sure everything shuts down I'd say give it thirty seconds or so), and plug it back in. As it restarts, it <strike>should</strike> may reset lock on the door (it might even conceivably do this when power is lost - I have no real insight into how this kind of electromechanical device works.)